# How does one dim very high LED loads with PWM?

Tags: pwm, light, dimming

Suppose we take a LED source that can be dimmed using PWM (i.e., by turning power on and off at high frequency). Dimmers exist for these sources up to, say, 5A at 24V. But what if I want to dim 10x the amount of loads (i.e, 50A worth), without using multiple dimmers? How can this be arranged? Is it possible, for example, to take the 24V dimmer output +/- signals and connect them as the driving signals of a very powerful solid-state relay? Are there any other options available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### That already exists in the LED lighting market

It's called an "amplifier".  [Here is an example](https://amzn.to/3GtXM6W).

It inputs PWM input from your dimmer.  It outputs PWM switched in sync with the input, at much higher current.  Typically there are 3-4 discrete channels because they are intended for RGB and RGBW dimming, and in a monochrome context you are welcome to have them feed different strings and drive them with the same signal (provided you understand these things are positive ground).

There is no limit to the number of amplifiers you can drive.

The input signal for the amplifier is simply the dimmer output that you would otherwise be sending to the lights directly.  In fact if your dimmer has 5A output, you can have it drive up to 5A of LEDs *and also* an unlimited number of amplifiers.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just apply a PWM voltage to LEDs unless they are internally current limited. For high power, series resistors as current limiters will dissipate a lot of power. A good dimmer design will use a series inductor to limit peak current and a parallel diode will maintain current with minimal ripple. If you want to adjust brightness over a full range, you will need inductors that can handle the current, and a high current driver.

Another approach would be to wire the LEDs in series, where the 5A will be sufficient, but you would need a high voltage supply and a MOSFET or SSR that can handle that voltage and current and PWM frequency. You might be able to drive the gate with the PWM of a 24 volt dimmer.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed Solid-State Relays made for switching DC Voltages with a DC control signal.

[image]

The datasheet of the SSR shown above says it whitstands up to 100A on the load side.

You can build this device with a couple mosfets and an optocoupler, but I think the best  solution is going with an off the shelf solution.

Another solution would be to just use a high power MOSFET.

[image]

Edit:Changed second schematic since it was not ok. (Add a resistor in series with the led to limit the current.

Comment: You would need to check the frequency response of the SSR to see if it can handle the PWM frequency. The MOSFET would not have that problem. But either approach may need current limiters for the LEDs if they are connected in parallel.

Comment: @PStechPaul True, I did not noticed that in the schematic, so the op would had to add a resistor in series with the load

Comment: I'd be concerned about your second schematic, charging the power FET's gate through such a high resistance. Use a gate driver.

Comment: (`Changed second schematic` ? I see no change.)